How save Printerdata setting in a file for further user in java
I am using swt for getting PrinterData of a printer by using below code
    public PrinterData getPrinterData(Display display, int pageCount) {
    //  PrinterData data = Printer.getDefaultPrinterData();
    PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog(display.getActiveShell(), SWT.NONE);
    PrinterData printerData = dialog.open();
    
    if (printerData == null) {
        System.out.println("Warning: No default printer.");
    }
    printerData.copyCount = pageCount;
    return printerData;
}

Above code sucessfully gives printerData
I want this printerData setting save in a file for directly getting printerData to read, instead of open a printer dialog.

I doubt that you can do that. The otherData field in PrinterData is in an unspecified format that may not be valid the next time you run the program.
